# Post JavaScript Object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, post

my JS is creating objects that look like this:

[image]

Now I want to post it to a PHP page.

What I tried is this:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(item_contents);
console.log(json);

jQ.post(
    "http://somedomain.com/headlines/save_items/", 
    json,
    function(data){
        console.log("Data: ");
        console.log(data);
        alert("first success");
    },
    "json"
)
.success(function() { 
    alert("second success"); 
})
.error(function(data) { 
    alert("error: "); 
    console.log(data);
})  
.complete(function() { 
    alert("complete"); 
});
```

...and the output is always an error. I'm using cakePHP..
Any help? TIA!!!

EDIT:

Currently, what i have on my php page is:

```
echo print_r($_POST);
```

and im getting a blank or undefined ouput..

Comment: Paste your PHP Code, where you are getting posted data.

Comment: Currently I have echo print_r($_POST);, im getting blank or undefined response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to post json, set variable name.

```
jQ.post(
    "http://somedomain.com/save_items.php", 
    {json: json}, //<--HERE
    function(data){
        console.log("Data: ");
        console.log(data);
        alert("first success");
    },
    "json"
)
.success(function() { 
    alert("second success"); 
})
.error(function(data) { 
    alert("error: "); 
    console.log(data);
})  
.complete(function() { 
    alert("complete"); 
});
```

In php use `echo $_POST['json'];`

you also may want to just post object itself:

```
jQ.post(url,object,function(data)
           {
                 console.log('success',data);
            }
           ,"json")
            .error(function(data) { 
                console.log('error',data);
             });
```

in php use `echo json_encode($_POST);`
be sure that *somedomain.com* is the same where js is.

Comment: Thanks @eicto, but it gives me Array([undefined] => undefined)

Comment: Hi eicto, I just removed the "json" datatype parameter just like Yograj Gupta suggested and it worked for me! Thanks guys!

Comment: it will work with "json" too if you return a json string back to client

Answer (score 1):

Post your json string with in a json literal object in your post function

like   { content: json },  -- and get this "content" in $_POST

```
jQ.post(
    "http://somedomain.com/save_items.php", 
    { content: json }, 
    function(data){
```

and in PHP try with

```
echo print_r($_POST["content"]);
```

Comment: @Mico, Just remove the "json" datatype from your `JQ.post`, might be your returning from php not a valid json data.

Comment: i removed the json datatype, it returns the success function, but the output is still Array
(
    [undefined] => undefined
)

Comment: @Mico, how would you want the output?